# Broadcast and service not working after clearing my app from recent app manager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-permissions

I am developing app like true caller. services and broadcasts working as per expectation in emulator but not working so well in my real device after clearing app from recent app.

I am using **Redmi 1's**. to test in real device.
when i clear app from recent app manager it not receive broadcast receiver and stop all services.

in the same device when i install truecaller it's working fine. when i check in 
**Setting->apps->running app** there is true caller **1 process and 1 service** always running in my device even after i clear it from recent app manager.

**how to achieve this types of functionality which always receives broadcast even after app cleared from  recent app manager?**